# How can I make this histogram in ggplot / R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Please find `My data q` below.

I have two covariates: `q$Studie` and `q$best.resp` corresponding to five different studies each reporting the best response obtained after a certain treatment.

`q$best.resp` has three levels

```
table(q$best.resp)

 0  1  2 
62 42  2
```

I want to produce a histogram that illustrate each `q$best.resp` per all `q$Studie` and all studies combined (corresponding to the `table(q$best.resp)`)

I have drawn this example of how I would like the plot to look like. Unfortunately, I have not succeeded through manuals.

[image]

I would prefer a solution in ggplot2. Please note that all studies only have `q$best.resp==0` or `q$best.resp==1` - except for `q$Studie==5`, that solitarily have two cases of `q$best.resp==2`

```
My data 
q <- structure(list(Studie = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), best.resp = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L)), .Names = c("Studie", 
"best.resp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -106L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
q %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Studie=as.character(Studie),
         best.resp =as.factor(best.resp)) %>% 
  bind_rows(., mutate(., Studie="all")) %>% 
  count(Studie, best.resp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Studie, n, fill= best.resp)) + 
   geom_col(position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That is very good! Can I manually assign colors to q$best.resp==0, 1 or 2? Eg. "#FF5599" and "blue"?

Comment: of course add `scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF5599", "blue", "grey"))`

Comment: Perfect! Maybe one more thing; is it possible to adjust the space between each bar? I would like the bars corresponding to each q$Studie to align without any space in between.

Comment: check `?position_dodge2()` and try `padding = 0`